# Best way to adjust font size with width and height of UILabel

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I have a `UILabel`that grows according to the screen size (Using auto resizing). However, the font isn't upscaling. I tried setting the label's `adjustFontSizeToFitWidth` property to YES, but it isn't working. Here is my code.

```
 override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        outLabel.numberOfLines = 1
        outLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        outLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center  
    }
```

I am not sure what to do at all. The font size stays the same no matter what.

Comment: is it growing vertically as well as horizontally ?

Comment: Yes., the label growing both horizontally and vertically using auto resizing.

Comment: The font isn't supposed to update based on the label size. Maybe setting a large initial font size would work with `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth`, otherwise update the font in layoutSubviews based on the frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented something similar to this and the way I solved the problem is by setting the font size at a high number to begin with. `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` should work to downscale your font size according to the width.

For example, set font size at 20 and `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` will downscale the font size to fit current UILabel width.

I hope this helps.